# Why does ECC signature verification need random numbers (sometimes taking a long time) in OpenSSL 1.1?

Tags: linux, openssl, cryptography, embedded-linux

I was working on a Linux boot-time (kinit) signature checker using ECC certificates, changing over
from raw RSA signatures to CMS-format ECC signatures. In doing so, I found the 
`CMS_Verify()` function stalling until the kernel printed "crng init done", indicating it needed to [wait for there to be enough system entropy for cryptographically secure random number generation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/random.7.html). Since nothing else is going on in the system, this took about 90 seconds on a Beaglebone Black.

This surprised me, I would have expected secure random numbers to be needed for certificate generation or maybe for signature generation, but there aren't any secrets to protect in public-key signature verification. So what gives?

(I figured it out but had not been able to find the solution elsewhere, so the answer is below for others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through a painstaking debug-by-printf process (my best option given it's a kinit), I found that a fundamental ECC operation uses random numbers as a defense against side-channel attacks. This is called "blinding" and helps prevent attackers from sussing out secrets based on how long computation takes, cache misses, power spikes, etc. by adding some indeterminacy.

From comments deep within the OpenSSL source:

```
/*-
* Computes the multiplicative inverse of a in GF(p), storing the result in r.
* If a is zero (or equivalent), you'll get a EC_R_CANNOT_INVERT error.
* Since we don't have a Mont structure here, SCA hardening is with blinding.
*/
int ec_GFp_simple_field_inv(const EC_GROUP *group, BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a,
                            BN_CTX *ctx)
```

and that function goes on to call `BN_priv_rand_range()`.

But in a public-key signature verification there are no secrets to protect. To solve the problem, in my kinit I just pre-seeded the OpenSSL random number generator with a fixed set of randomly-chosen data, as follows:

```
    RAND_seed( "\xe5\xe3[...29 other characters...]\x9a", 32 );
```

DON'T DO THAT if your program works with secrets or generates any keys, signatures, or random numbers. In a signature-checking kinit it's OK. In a program that required more security I could have seeded with data from the on-chip RNG hardware (/dev/hw_random), or saved away some entropy in secure storage if I had any, or sucked it up and waited for crng init done.